# Use of unresolved type MutableProperty

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-5

I am trying to declare a property in view model that i will later bind to a view..

```
  class LoginViewModel {

     let myProperty = MutableProperty("")//error here undeclared type MutableProperty

    }
```

I am using ReactiveCocoa '5.0.0-alpha.3'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ReactiveCocoa [was split into `ReactiveCocoa` and `ReactiveSwift`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#repository-split), you'll probably need to import `@import ReactiveSwift` in your file as well as `@import ReactiveCocoa`

Also, if you're adding ReactiveCocoa via Carthage, dont forget to also add the `ReactiveSwift.framework` to your Project.

Comment: Thanks..i am new to RAC..Can you please tell me how to print the textfield values.. I tried using this but no thing happens `self.nameTextField.reactive.trigger(for: .valueChanged).map{
            
            print("textfield value is \($0)")
            
            }`

Answer (score 0):

To monitor the textField/ textView values changed, this code works for me:

```
passwordTF.reactive.continuousTextValues.observeValues({ print("the new value is \($0!)") })
```

And the console log like this:

```
the new value is q
the new value is qw
the new value is qwe
the new value is qwer
```

There is a other method to monitor the value when the editing is ended:

```
passwordTF.reactive.textValues.observeValues({ print("the new value is \($0!)") })
```

And the console log the result in one line:

```
the new value is qwer
```

Comment: thanks..But i cant filter the text with this `self.nameTextField.reactive.trigger(for: .editingChanged)`

Comment: i am trying to do this for a text field http://nshipster.com/reactivecocoa/

Comment: @Costello  passwordTF.reactive.continuousTextValues.filter { ($0?.characters.count)! > 3 }.observeValues { print($0!) }

Comment: Thanks can you please give me an example how to do for action..may be observe an action or do some thing?

Comment: But why doesnot this calls `let isValidUserName =   nameTextField.reactive.continuousTextValues.filter {
            
            print( ($0?.characters.count)! > 3)
            return ($0?.characters.count)! > 3
        }`

Comment: Because you need to `observe` a signal. But anyway, I'm pretty sure filter is not what you want, judging by the name of your result (`isValidUsername`), because `filter` will just block values that do not pass the predicate. If you intended `isValidUserName` to be a boolean that indicates wether the text in the TextField is longer than 3 characters, I'd try this: `let isValidUserName = textField.reactive.continuousTextValues.map { ($0?.characters.count ?? 0) > 3 }` and then `isValidUserName.observeValues{ print("valid? \($0)")}`